# SSIS tab delimited csv flat file import, import as ragged right, replaces tabs with spaces

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ucs2

I have tab delimited csv's with UCS-2 LE encoding that I need to import to SQL using SSIS.  I intend to bring multiple files in using SSIS and parse to various tables and columns either within SSIS (preferred) or in SQL.  I am using 65001 (UTF-8) code page on the flat file connection, "Unicode" is checked because we have some special characters in the file.

In the preview page, I can see what appears to be my tabs in the source file.  However, when I use the flat file connection as a source, the tabs become spaces in the output, whether to a table, or to another flat file.

Is there a way to import UCS-2LE csv's as ragged right and retain the tabs in the output column?

[image: general tab]

Comment: You seem have have a lot of conflicting terminology in this question. Tab-delimited files are not the same thing as CSVs (Comma-Separated Values), which are not the same thing as Ragged Right, so you should not conflate the three. UCS-2 LE is not the same encoding as UTF-8. UCS-2 files always use two bytes per code point and are more compatible with UTF-16 than UTF-8, but are still not quite the same as UTF-16 (UCS-2 is a subset). When importing UCS-2 files you should tick `Unicode` and that should grey out the `Code Page` setting because it's irrelevant.

Comment: Editing your question to add some sample data may help to get the right answer(s).